# MS Chart - Draw Full Height Rectangular Area

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

How to draw rectangular area from the bottom to the top of a MS Chart, starting and ending on specific DateTime.

I succeed to add area from 0 to Max. I add this area before the other series.

```
chart.Series.Add("Stagnation");
chart.Series["Stagnation"].Points.AddXY(stagnation.StartTime, stagnation.MaxBalance);
chart.Series["Stagnation"].Points.AddXY(stagnation.EndTime, stagnation.MaxBalance);
chart.Series["Stagnation"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedArea;
chart.Series["Stagnation"].Color = Color.FromArgb(100, R, G, B);
```

Where `stagnation.StartTime` and `stagnation.EndTime` are DateTime.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use an `Annotation`? An `ImageAnnotation` can display a tiny semitransparent image, strechted to match the size you want. I don't know how to send it behind the data, even though there is a SendtoBack function.. You can make it `ClipToChartArea`. - Or you could stay with your additional series and calculate the rounded ceiling of the data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called `StripLine` which are used as shown below

```
StripLine sline = new StripLine();
sline.IntervalOffset = <the start point>;
sline.StripWidth = <the duration>;
//sline.Text = "You can set a label";
sline.Interval = 0.0D; // IMPORTANT: prevent repeating striplines
sline.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
sline.BorderColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
Chart.AxisX.StripLines.Add(sline);
```

By default striplines are designed to be repeated every `Interval` but you can define single instances by setting `Interval = 0`.

Comment: `public double IntervalOffset` I need to set X coordinate in DateTime but IntervalOffset takes double. Can it be fixed?

Comment: try using `DateTime.ToOADate()` as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190843/ms-charts-c-sharp-line-chart-not-accurate-on-data-with-gaps